# Xamarin - get control dimensions

Tags: xamarin.forms

I really don't know how to get control dimensions in Xamarin Forms. I thought it would be as easy as:

```
View control = GetControlSomehow();
var bounds = control.Bounds;
```

But View.Bounds returns different things depending on wether the control is inside a grid or not; or wether the main layout is AbsoluteLayout or some other one.

For example if I do something like:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Button AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="200,200" x:Name="btn" Text="Btn"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

then I am not able to read actual height or width of that button. Although MSDN says that Height & Width properties should return these values.

I tried even:

```
var width = ctrl.Width;
```

or

```
var width = ctrl.GetValue(WidthProperty);
```

But really non of these worked. I always get -1

So how can I get the control dimensions that could be reliable?

Comment: how are you trying to read Height and Width?  Are you waiting until after the layout completes before attempting?

Comment: It's all loaded. For example, when my page appears I click some button and then want to get the dimensions

Comment: To help others in the future with a similar problem, please add to your question **the code that did not work**. Then this becomes a complete Q&A showing what did not work, and showing answers about alternative ways to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete example showing how to pass button itself, using data binding.

AbsoluteLayoutPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestBugs.AbsoluteLayoutPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <Button AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="200,200" x:Name="btn" Text="Btn"
                    Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{x:Reference btn}"/>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

AbsoluteLayoutPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace TestBugs
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class AbsoluteLayoutPage : ContentPage
    {
        public AbsoluteLayoutPage()
        {
            ButtonCommand = new Command(ButtonClick);
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        private void ButtonClick(object ob)
        {
            var button = ob as View;
            var bounds = btn.Bounds;
            var width = btn.Width;
            var height = btn.Height;
            Debug.WriteLine($"--- ButtonClick {bounds}, ({width},{height})---");

        }

        public Command ButtonCommand { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When click button, in VS Output pane:

```
[0:] --- ButtonClick {X=200 Y=200 Width=88 Height=48}, (88,48)---
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
<Button Text="Click" Clicked="Clicked"  />

public void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs a)
    {
        var btn = (Button)sender;

        var w = btn.Width;
        var h = btn.Height;

        DisplayAlert("Dimesions", $"{w}x{h}","OK");

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I just get -1

Comment: @AdamJachocki - Please **add the not-working code to question**. I've confirmed Jason's answer works, on both Android and UWP. Therefore, the issue is in how you are using it. NOTE: "-1" means you are testing a view that *has not been laid out*. (Which occurs just before it becomes visible on screen.) Somehow, you aren't referring to the actual button that is visible on the screen. OR you are referring to a value it had before it became visible. OR there is something else in the XAML, that you have not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, my bad.
I was testing it on two pages - the real one and the test one. The test page is built in a different way and I confirm that the problem was in time when I retrieved these values. Control wasn't painted yet.

So I am really sorry to bother you and thank you all for investing your time into this.

Comment: No problem - it happens to us all. Glad you got it sorted out!